# android listview onclick --subitem should be populated under it

Tags: android, listview

On click of certain listview items, I need to show sub item under the item clicked.
Could some one please throw some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about **Expandable List** then just look at this example.

[ExpandableList1.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html)

Also this [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try out an `ExpandableListView` in Android.